# Typescript index signature and methods

Tags: typescript

Why does the following code give `ts(2411)` error?

```js
class Greeter {
    [key: string]: string | number[];
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet(): string {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}
```

The error is at `greet()` which says `type '() => string'` not assignable to `type 'string | number[]'`.

The error goes away if I add `object` to index signature. Why is that?

Also for index signature, is it using `any` bad practice?

Edit: I also added interface `Function` to the signature. It works as well. Still, the question is why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any properties or methods declared in the class or interface with index signature must have type compatible with what you have in the index. That's why adding `Function` to the index signature helps.

The reason is [explained in the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types):

> While string index signatures are a powerful way to describe the
>   “dictionary” pattern, they also enforce that all properties match
>   their return type. This is because a string index declares that
>   `obj.property` is also available as `obj["property"]`. In the following
>   example, name’s type does not match the string index’s type, and the
>   type-checker gives an error:

```
interface NumberDictionary {
    [index: string]: number;
    length: number;    // ok, length is a number
    name: string;      // error, the type of 'name' is not a subtype of the indexer
}
```

Adding `any` to the indexer signature can be considered a bad practice,
because `any` suppress typechecking and any value obtained in any way from `any` also has `any` type unless explicitly declared otherwise, so having `any` increases chances that you have type errors which are not reported by the compiler.

Adding `Function` to the type is better, because it correctly describes the actual data contained in the class - when you use indexed access to get a value like this

```
  const key = 'greeting';
  const value = this[key];
```

you might get a function as a value if `key` happens to be equal to `'greet'`. Also, when you assign string value to `greet`:

```
  this['greet'] = 'hi!';
```

the method will be overwritten with a string value and you won't be able to call it any more.

Considering all that, it's better to keep dictionary with index signature in separate property of the class, not in the class itself. Something like this could work:

```
class Greeter {
    data: { [key: string]: string | number[] } = {};

    get greeting(): string { return this.data.greeting.toString() }
    set greeting(value: string) { this.data.greeting = value };

    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet(): string {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are methods evaluated? I mean why both `object` and `Function` solve the problem?

Comment: because `Function` is a subtype of `object`, so adding `object` also makes method types compatible with index signature.

Comment: Super helpful! So, in your final example, you'd index the object like: `myGreeter.data["greeting"] = "my new greeting"`, right? Which, since `data` is also typed to take a `number[]`, could be `myGreeter.data["greetingNumbers"] = [ 4, 2 ]`, correct?

Comment: [yes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDiBOBTRAXR9oG8BQ0-QBMwUwAuLaAbQGtEBPciFeASwDsBzAXUefY+gAfaGwCuAWwBG6Sl2gBfaAF4s8gNzZc+DqmgckqfgAoAlL1acKSFKPhtoKABYsIAOiIlX+5Cn6uUAPYAynycpgpaeBC63oZhAG5gIKKI5vwmFE4u7sRgXga+liqJyYgKGpHQwAFsTPCiwIHwRuKIUGA6aZwZOPh9Ds5usYUCKq3tOhp98pXDpl0Cvf141rb2AEQAEoggIAEANNDr0ADUA9nD-FP4MzPY1bUo0OJ0CD7oyiKIAO5wBehGADkgJMGheb1Q6ByJEo60unHWchU6xeX1+8I46zBr3+8GhYFhGIAchJpPAIIjPpRoAAWQ4AJmgXGxELQeI8BLhBX4lJUlAArMzcEA), although it also allows `myGreeter.data["greeting"] = [5];`

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround that allows you to accomplish that.
In my case, I wanted to have a class which had index signature plus a custom setter and a property `all` which returned all the values (so I could avoid ugly `Object.values` when using that class).

This is an example.

```
interface IAccessor<T> {
    [key: string]: T;
}

interface IGetter<T> {
    all: T[]
}

class Accessor<T> {

    get all(): T[] {
        return Object.values<T>(this);
    }

    [key: string]: T | any; // any will do the trick, but it's not enough
}

const accessor: IAccessor<string> & IGetter<string> = new Accessor<string>();
accessor.first = "a";
accessor.second = "b";
accessor.third = "c";
console.log(accessor.all); // ["a", "b", "c"]
```

[Plaground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEEFIM7YPZQA8AKgHzIDeAUMrcgNoDWEAngFzLZhSgDmAuh2IBuKgF8qVUJFiIUqAOIQwMkuWp1kcADbah9fuMkJtcXMkw58RMpUmbeyrboAUASn387mzVGUBXKBBkAHkAIwArCAQwADoANx1-CGw1FzAAC2BsN1FNCRo6JlYOLh4QASFkAB8tEBZhZAB6JrqWZAB3YF1kABM8ZEyUbmAERgAaZDD-MGRgMABybGQQPFmIVf9eDKMqBDwQLi0sFOsODBPcAkIyvnIAMjQlFWgbkYryAF4ViA6LS%20sb3KvFI7lEiCsBFiMGAUCO3wARHAEeCAVDsNEDr1kIiwiiqBDTlDMrDsYiEPj9oc8NoILFtHheC5CVcoLEdNpcs1WvQkQjJgi8QKKfwgA)