# Extend record type with a toList function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want a "toList" function on the generic record type. Is there a way to achieve something like this?
**Edit**: It must not be a solution with the record type. I am just searching for something similar, where I can still use *myDictionary["key"]*.

```
//this is possible
type MyRecord<K extends string, T> = Record<K, T> & {
    toList(this: MyRecord<K, T>): T[];
} 

//this not. Typescript complains here about using MyRecord as value when it is a type
MyRecord.prototype.toList = function():T[] {
    const list: T[] = [];
    ...
    return list;
};
```

Where I can use it later like this without having to define a toList function on every assignment.

```
//this won't work, toList is missing;
const myDictionary: MyRecord<string, string> = { "a": "b", "c": "d" } 
const myDictionaryValues = myDictionary.toList();
myDictionaryValues.forEach(v => console.log(v));
//prints:
//b
//d
```

Neither the *MyRecord.prototype* is working nor the declaration in the first line of my use case example (because of the missing "toList").

I know that it is possible to just have a global function somewhere, which is doing the "toList" thing. That is not what I am asking here.

Comment: Your type doesn't exist at runtime, you can't add to its prototype as it doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes thank you. That is the reason why it is not working. I am searching for something to work around the problem. Having a "dictionary" class won't help because then I cannot use indexers, right?

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no way to define a TypeScript object type with both an index signature and properties that don't match that signature. [Typescript index signature and methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054226/typescript-index-signature-and-methods)

So, you can't extend a record type with additional functions, unless it's a record of functions (or you forego type safety altogether and use `any`).

You could perhaps compose the underlying record as a property, like so:

```
class MyRecord<K extends string, T> {
    data: Record<K, T> = {} as Record<K, T>;

    toList(): T[] {
        return Object.values(this.data);
    }
}
```